# An error in arithmetic operation app in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating an app with following requirements and having been someone with slightly none coding experience, I need help:

> Create a calculator that does one arithmetic operation at a time and prints the result to the screen.
>
> Prompt the user for a number.
> Prompt the user for an operation (+ - / *).
> Prompt the user for another number.
> Perform the operation.
> Repeat until the user types in "quit" at any of the prompts.

It it doesn't work as intended.
it doesn't stop when I type `quit`.
How can I add this feature?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Arithmetic_Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x, y;
            char operation;

            while (true)
            {            
                Console.Write("Enter a number or type \"quit\" to exit: ");
                String entry = Console.ReadLine();

                // Prompt user for the first number
                Console.Write("Enter the first number:  ");
                x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                // Prompt the user for an operation (+ - / *).
                Console.Write("Enter an operation ");
                operation = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                // Prompt user for next number
                Console.Write("Enter the next number ");
                y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (entry.ToLower() == "quit")
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (operation == '+')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, x + y);
                }
                else if (operation == '-')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", x, y, x - y);
                }
                else if (operation == 'x')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", x, y, x * y);
                }
                else if (operation == '/')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", x, y, x / y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to break sooner.

Comment: Of course it stops when you type `quit`. You (or your user) just has to do some further inputs to satisfy the next three invocations of Console.ReadLine following below `String entry = Console.ReadLine();` until your code reaches the `if` statement with the exit-test and exits...

Comment: "quit at any prompt" - you don't check that. 1) readline, 2) break at quit, 3) next input

Answer (score 1):

The if condition to check the value of entry should be moved immediately after collecting the input from user.
Try:

```
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the first number or type \"quit\" to exit: ");
            String entry = Console.ReadLine();
            if (entry.ToLower() == "quit")
            {
                break;
            }
            x = Convert.ToInt32(entry);

            // Prompt the user for an operation (+ - / *).
            Console.Write("Enter an operation ");
            operation = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            // Prompt user for next number
            Console.Write("Enter the next number ");
            y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Your still asking for three numbers.  :-)